# Event Handler on MenuBar

Tags: 2007, development, event-handlers, survey-list

**whats sharepoint renderingtemplate is and how can I use it to add event handler to "Respond to this survey" link button**

For last couple of days I have been researching on how to add some kind of event receiver to "Respond to this survey" link button.

I am not really sure where this button came from as if its part of a form or a view but I came across [THIS](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pavankumar/how-to-hide-respond-to-this-survey-when-a-user-has-already-responded-to-the-survey) tutorial which is doing something similar however it didn't worked for me without any errors in ULS log or event receiver.

Also I am confused with all of the coding "Elements" in ascx file in tutorial and if someone can explain them to me please.

Note: We have customized survey module of SharePoint so its not out of box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I searched a lot but I am not able to find a way to set event handler on "Respond to Survey" link button because its just a link which is added to menu bar, however I created a custom new form and added my code in page_load method of Custom New Form.aspx.

hope it helps :).

Answer (score 0):

i think this might give you some insight as someone tryd to do somthing very similar:

> "Respond to this Survey" is rendered by <SharePoint:NewMenu
> AccessKey="<%$Resources:wss,tb_NewMenu_AK%>" runat="server" />.

That is your answer right there :) , you need to create a class that can overwrite sharepoint link button :).

You need to create a class that inherits from the following: `Microsoft.Sharepoint.WebControls.NewMenu`

for a detailed explantation with steps in how to do it follow this:

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pavankumar/how-to-hide-respond-to-this-survey-when-a-user-has-already-responded-to-the-survey)

Yes its for hiding the button but instead of hiding you can assign it an event to override (click event) and do what you want to do ;)

hope it helps :)